# How to count already open IE windows? objShell.Windows is returning too many results

Tags: vba

I've tried to code how many IE windows now open and what URL those are.

```
Sub Test()

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows

For Each Window In AllWindows
    MsgBox Window.LocationURL
Next

end sub
```

when i run the code, it shows many URL of 21 ea even if i open only one IE website.
I guess it shows URL history..

I want to see URL of IE website that i open now.

Would you give me any advice?

Comment: The code is working fine for me and displays only the open IE windows.

Comment: ah??  for real? It still doesn't work for me.. i close all IE but it print many URLs

Comment: Try using Task manager to close all the instances of IE before running the code.

Comment: Possibly you have hidden instances of IE running?

Comment: hmm hidden of IE running? i have no idea about it, anyway Thanks Yasser and Tim

Comment: Not too make you paranoid, but if you really have 20 hidden instances of IE, you might have some malware running. On the other hand, if you are experimenting with scripting IE, a bug in your own code might be opening these instances.